# How can i redirect unstructured link like (https://example.com/digital-marketing.php/ercbierubcrei) using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

There is a issue of unstructured link like (https://example.com/digital-marketing.php/ercbierubcrei)

How can I redirect its to main root?

My .htaccess not working, I'm using below code in .htaccess:-

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a issue of unstructured link like (`https://example.com/digital-marketing.php/ercbierubcrei`)
>
> How can I redirect its to main root?

I assume `/digital-marketing.php` is a file on your filesystem. In which case `/ercbierubcrei` is *additional pathname information* (or *path-info*). By default, the PHP handler allows path-info, so `/digital-marketing.php` is still served but at the different URL (if that's what you mean by "unstructured link"?).

You can simply disable path-info on these URLs by setting the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

Now, any URL that contains path-info will trigger a 404 instead and your custom 404 error document will be called. (You can still override this behaviour with mod_rewrite if you wish.)

Alternatively, if you wanted to *redirect* `/digital-marketing.php/ercbierubcrei` to `/digital-marketing.php` (is that what you mean by "redirect its to main root"?<sup>***1**</sup>) then you can do something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)/ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This redirects a URL of the form `/<something>.php/<anything>` to `/<something.php`, effectively discarding the path-info portion of the URL.

(<sup>***1**</sup> - If by "main root" you do literally mean the document root of the site then that is not recommended. Google would likely treat this as a soft-404 anyway. A custom 404 with a meaningful message would be preferable.)

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 /example.com
> ```

This does not look "valid". The 2nd argument to the `ErrorDocument` directive should ideally be a local URL-path to the document that handles the error response.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-documents/my-404-error-document.php
```

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite its working fine for me. thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

A simple 301 redirect will do the job.

```
redirect 301 /old_url http://www.domainroot.com/
```

Comment: actually there is more links like this so i want to one solution for it, i cant define for each page because there is approx 400 pages.

Comment: @RohitVerma then you will obviously have to find some kind of pattern these URLs can be identified by first, you can not just go and say they are “unstructured”, and then expect there was a solution based on that.

Answer (score 0):

use Complete url of your site. Like this

> ErrorDocument 404 https://www.yourdomain.com/example.php

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below `.htaccess` examples:

**Redirect `http://yourdomain/digital-marketing.php/apple` to `http://yourdomain/`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /digital-marketing.php/*
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

**Redirect `http://yourdomain/digital-marketing.php/orange` to `http://yourdomain/ref?code=orange`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /digital-marketing.php/*
RewriteRule ^digital-marketing.php/(.*)$ /ref?code=$1 [L,R=301]
```